# Inventory Attribute column in Kit Assembly

Tags: c#, acumatica

I need to have an InventoryItem Attribute as a column in Kit Assembly screen (IN307000) on Stock Components grid.

I am able to get the Attribute column on grid but not its value. Can anyone please suggest what is missing in below code.

Here is the code I have written-

```html
public class PXAddAtttributeColumns : CRAttributesFieldAttribute
{
 string[] _names;

 public PXAddAtttributeColumns(string[] names, Type classID, Type noteID)
  : base(classID, noteID)
 {
  _names = names;
 }

 public override void CacheAttached(PXCache sender)
 {
  this._IsActive = true;
  base.CacheAttached(sender);
 }

 protected override void AttributeFieldSelecting(PXCache sender, PXFieldSelectingEventArgs e, PXFieldState state, string attributeName, int idx)
 {
  if (_names.Any(attributeName.Equals))
  {
   state.DisplayName = (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(state.DisplayName)) ? (state.DisplayName.Replace("$Attributes$-", "")) : attributeName;
   state.Visible = true;
   state.Visibility = PXUIVisibility.Dynamic;
  }

  base.AttributeFieldSelecting(sender, e, state, attributeName, idx);
 }
}

public class INComponentTranExtension : PXCacheExtension<INComponentTran>
{
 public abstract class itemAttributes : IBqlField { }

 [PXAddAtttributeColumns(new[] { "Attrib101" }, typeof(InventoryItem.itemClassID), typeof(INComponentTran.noteID))]
 public virtual string[] ItemAttributes { get; set; }
}
```

Note: I am using Acumatica ver 6.10.0956

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare `ItemAttributes` field with `PXAddAtttributeColumns` attribute in Cache Extension for `InventoryItem` DAC.

The attributes are related to `InventoryItem` entity hence you need to reference `NoteID` and `ClassID` of `InventoryItem` DAC. Attribute information will be fetched as long as View tied with Grid works with `InventoryItem` DAC (in your case, Data View is `Components` and has inner join with `InventoryItem` DAC).

```cs
public class InventoryItemDemoPXExt : PXCacheExtension<InventoryItem>
{
    public abstract class itemAttributes : IBqlField { }

    [PXAddAtttributeColumns(new[] { "COLOR", "CONFIGURAB", "PIXELSIZE", "WIDEANGLE" },
                                    typeof(InventoryItem.itemClassID),
                                    typeof(InventoryItem.noteID))]
    public virtual string[] ItemAttributes { get; set; }
}
```

Make sure to specify `AutoGenerateColumns="AppendDynamic"` for `PXGrid` control for Framework to dynamically generate Attribute columns.

Fields will show up as below:

[image]
Note: This example is applicable to 6.1 series onward.

Comment: That seems working. Thank you Dhiren. I wonder, till now I was trying to have that attribute column in `INComponentTran` DAC. But interestingly it looks like it pulls the value from `InventoryItem` DAC.

Comment: The attributes are related to InventoryItem entity hence you need to reference InventoryItem.NoteId. Attribute information will be fetched as long as View (in your case, it is Components has inner join with InventoryItem) tied with Grid works InventoryItem DAC.

Comment: Thank you Dhiren.